# MenuStrip in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

Can someone please explain to me why the hell? When I try to set a MenuStrip Item calling it by name it gives me an exception?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Sample.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Either of the following statements cause errors.

```
frmMenu.MenuStripfrmMenu.Items(key:="Enter").Enabled = False

frmMenu.MenuStripfrmMenu.Items("Enter").Enabled = False
```

However when I call Items using an integer it works perfectly.

Comment: Nope it is just a plain text.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but what I am trying to do is ... there is a MenuStrip from Toolbox that I added to the form and made a list of all the menus (there are no sub-menus). What I am trying to do is disable some of the menus from the start and enable them as the  application runs. So I am setting some of the menus to be disabled. But I don't want to use this Items(0).Enabled = False is there a way to do something like this frmMenu.MenuStripfrmMenu.SOMETHING("Enter").Enabled = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the *name* property of the menu item, not the *text* property:

```
Public Sub New()
  InitializeComponent()

  Dim menu As New MenuStrip
  Dim menuOne As New ToolStripMenuItem("Menu One") With {.Name = "menuOne"}
  Dim menuTwo As New ToolStripMenuItem("Menu Two") With {.Name = "menuTwo"}
  menu.Items.Add(menuOne)
  menu.Items.Add(menuTwo)
  Me.Controls.Add(menu)

  menu.Items("menuOne").Enabled = False
  AddHandler menu.Items("menuTwo").Click, AddressOf Menu_Click
End Sub

Private Sub Menu_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  MessageBox.Show("This menu works.")
End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect. Need to change it a little but pretty much what I needed. Thank you.